# How can I get Codeship to pass the check_url phase of a nodejs expressjs deployment on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, codeship

So in a nutshell I am trying to:
Deploy - https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html
through Codeship and from Codeship to Heroku.

I have been trying to follow the very basic **Hello-World express tutorial** from https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html but then the codeship **check_url** phase **fails** to load properly over Heroku getting the following error:

```
    Connecting to intfdsf-dsfdfsdf-323423.herokuapp.com (intfdsf-dsfdfsdf-323423.herokuapp.com)|54.243.89.187|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
    2016-07-22 02:18:12 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

Under the **Setup Command** I have tried the following:

```
    nvm install 0.10
    nvm use 0.10
    npm install
```

and

```
    nvm install 6.3.0
    nvm use 6.3.0
    npm install
```

**Both have failed the same way.**

And adding something like `npm start` hangs the process on that line....

I have added a Procfile with `web: node server.js` and so renamed app.js to server.js just in case and for best practices. And finally I do have `engines` defined in my `package.json` as such:

```
    {
        "name": "node-ship",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "",
        "main": "server.js",
        "engines": {
            "node": "5.6.x",
            "npm": "3.10.x"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "start" : "node server.js",
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
        },
        "repository": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git+https://github.com/slfkjsdlfjklsdkfj/node-ship.git"
        },
        "author": "slfkjsdlfjklsdkfj",
        "license": "ISC",
        "bugs": {
            "url": "https://github.com/slfkjsdlfjklsdkfj/node-ship/issues"
        },
        "homepage": "https://github.com/slfkjsdlfjklsdkfj/node-ship#readme",
        "dependencies": {
            "express": "^4.14.0"
        }
    }
```

What am I missing? So that I can get Heroku to load properly expressjs just like it loads locally when I run `node app.js`

Thank you for your help.

Here is the server.js file also:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!');
    });

    app.listen(5000, function () {
        console.log('Example app listening on port 5000!');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `check_url` script run by Codeship at the end of the Heroku deployment uses `wget` to check the status code of the root URL of your Heroku application. (If you want to check a different URL, there is a setting hidden behind the *More Options* link).

As long as that page returns a status code in the 2xx or 3xx range the check will succeed.

See https://github.com/codeship/scripts/blob/master/utilities/check_url.sh for the full script.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku relies on the use of a port environmental variable.

So the `server.js` file should have instead:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port '+ port +'!');
});
```

Emphasis on the `var port = ...` part

Then the Procfile will take care of the rest with its `web: node server.js`